# How to disable widgets in Appsmith？

Tags: appsmith

`const widgetNames = ['Input_remark', 'Input_Date', 'Input_Birthday'];  widgetNames.forEach(widgetName => { const widget = Appsmith.Widgets[widgetName];  if (widget) { widget.isDisabled = true; } }); }}`

I put the code in the JS of the button, but it says 'Appsmith' is not defined. I don't know what to do? Can you help me?

I know the best solution is to create a new function to do it, but I don't know how to write this function, please